# Redirect users to different pages based on session data in LARAVEL

Tags: laravel

How to redirect another page when creating anchor tag using Ajax with data table

```
$btn = '<a href="'.{{ route('Userdata.edit') }}.'" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$row->id.'" data-original-title="Edit" class="edit btn btn-primary edit-user">
                            <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </a>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp'; 
                    $btn = $btn.'<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Delete" data-id="'.$row->id.'" class="delete-user btn btn-danger">
                            <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </a>';
```

I want to redirect when user click on edit button

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
if (session('key') === 'A') {
    redirect('bPage');
} else if (session('key') === 'B') {
    redirect('bPage');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your view check the value as follows

```
@if({{Session::get('response')}} === 'A')
   <a href=""></a>
@else if({{Session::get('response')}} === 'B')
   <a href=""></a>
@endif
```

In your controller you can use

```
if (Session::get('response') === 'A') {
    redirect('bPage');
 } else if (Session::get('response') === 'B') {
    redirect('bPage');
 }
```